# how to disallow to use the same id for a few elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to detect an usage of the same id in the different XML layouts of an Android project.

It's critical to my project, each element must have their own unique id!

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Why do you need that, can you elaborate?

Comment: I need it to logging purposes.

Comment: why based on ids? Every view backed by an adapter will have in general same ids for its items.

Comment: I just need to prevent a ussage of the same id in the different XML layouts. It should not be possible to use the same id in the two different XML layouts. I need it to have a way to map element id to a XML layout.